# Advanced Custom Fields not saving at all now

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, field

I downloaded and installed Advanced Custom Fields 4.1.6 the other day and I used it a few times for some time and it worked perfectly, but for some reason now none of my custom fields seem to be saving and I'm not getting any errors or anything. I don't think that I have done anything at all that could have possibly broken this.

Has this happened to anyone else? And what could possibly be the issue?

Comment: Maybe a conflicting plugin? Try deactivating other plugins and see which one breaks it..

Comment: Well I only have that one plugin activated so it can't be that

Comment: Weird, never had any issue. Latest wordpress? WP_DEBUG enabled?

Comment: Yes, both.

Hmm, I am new with Wordpress and this plugin, I have like registered the custom fields in my functions.php (I have to right? a little confused about that) but that didn't seem to work either, and I'm quite certain that I did them right because I watched a tutorial and everything.. hmm

Comment: I never have to do anything in the functions.php for this plugin. You can configure it all through the admin, there's a "Custom Fields" admin section for it (near the bottom in the admin menu)

Comment: Okay then that must have been something unrelated, and actually I just changed from my custom theme to the default, and upon doing that they save perfectly.. So it seems to be an issue within my theme, but I'm not sure what would be the cause of that, especially since i have like 2 files in my theme so far...

Comment: Odd. Maybe check your error log...

Comment: Nothing is showing up in those

Comment: Can't think of anything else, maybe check on the author's forum, he's pretty good at helping out.

Comment: Have you tried switching to default theme? I confirm with @Ben that you don't have to touch anything in your `functions.php` file to make the plugin work.

Comment: I have switched to the default theme, and it works fine then. So it is with my theme that it's breaking, however I'm not sure what would be causing this to break. I have gone through messed with different files and such to try to determine the error, but I can't seem to find it. I don't have hardly any files either. It had been working with my theme previously (this morning actually), but I don't know what happened now. I haven't really changed anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have to take a look at export function the plugin provides. Select a field group you created and hit export. It'll generate some code which is pretty good commented with tips and advice. There might be some information there for good use for 'ya.

Example by the plugin developer:

**Include in theme**

The Advanced Custom Fields plugin can be included within a theme. To do so, move the ACF plugin inside your theme and add the following code to your functions.php file:

```
include_once('advanced-custom-fields/acf.php');
```

To remove all visual interfaces from the ACF plugin, you can use a constant to enable lite mode. Add the following code to your functions.php file before the include_once code:

```
define( 'ACF_LITE', true );
```

Hope it helps.

/Paul

Comment: Thanks, but when I do this I get a fatal error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare acf_filter_post_id() (previously declared in /home/ohsinc/public_html/dev/sagesure/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/core/api.php:21) in /home/ohsinc/public_html/dev/sagesure/wp-content/themes/sagesure/advanced-custom-fields/core/api.php on line 65

Comment: Ok I've figured out what's going on i think. It seems to be doing this only for the "homepage" page, however I can add them and everything on to any other page in my site and it works fine. So for some reason it just won't work on my homepage, which is also renamed to "home-2.php" in my files, because that's what it had to be to work. maybe that has something to do with it? idk, it still shows up in the list of "show the field group if Page is equal to Home"

Comment: Hi, sorry I haven't had the time to respond, I'll try tomorrow. ATM i'm on my phone.

Comment: The reason of the fatal error is probably that you still had the plugin activated when you used the export function. The home-2.php.. I have no idea what that could be. Try stuff in the twentyeleven theme to rule out any theme issues. Normally when you install ACF there is nothing to be done in any file to get the plugin working. The only thing you do is add some php to retrieve the data like: <? the_field('field_name');?>

Answer (score 1):

Since my rep isn't high enough to reply to @Kortschot's response, I'll comment here.

I got this error while testing a new theme. It appears the theme has ACF bundled into the theme, which triggers the "Cannot redeclare acf_filter_post_id()" error. For obvious reasons (you can't run two instances of the plugin in the same install). @Kortschot's reference to including ACF in a theme helped solve my problem.

Now I have to figure out how to access ACF if I want to customize fields on pages/posts...

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go ahead and reply to this old question in hopes that it helps someone out. I have been having this problem where my fields would not update on my custom posts. I usually have multiple tabs open to make navigation easier in the backend of WP. It turns out that when I closed all other tabs except the current one I'm editing, the fields update every time!

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with Advanced custom fields plugin , i resolve my issue by adding one line code in advanced-custom-fields/core/controllers/post.php

```
add_action('pre_post_update', array($this, 'save_post'));
```

after

```
add_action('save_post',array($this, 'save_post'), 10, 1);
```

line number 33, 34.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by creating unique field names.